# How to change ip of dart frog server from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 ( or actual LAN ip)

Tags: dart, ip

For [Dart Frog](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_frog) server I can start it using

```
dart_frog dev --port 8090
```

but then it is only accessible from127.0.0.1:8090,

I want it to be available from other machine in same local area network using local IP (e.g 192.168.0.10), so wanted to specify 0.0.0.0

But could not find a way to change it.

Comment: have you found a way?

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you're calling `serve`, it appears that the second parameter can be a variety of things, including '0.0.0.0':
https://pub.dev/documentation/dart_frog/latest/dart_frog/serve.html.  Drilling down, we find the address ultimately as:

```
  /// The [address] can either be a [String] or an
  /// [InternetAddress]. If [address] is a [String], [bind] will
  /// perform a [InternetAddress.lookup] and use the first value in the
  /// list. To listen on the loopback adapter, which will allow only
  /// incoming connections from the local host, use the value
  /// [InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4] or
  /// [InternetAddress.loopbackIPv6]. To allow for incoming
  /// connection from the network use either one of the values
  /// [InternetAddress.anyIPv4] or [InternetAddress.anyIPv6] to
  /// bind to all interfaces or the IP address of a specific interface.
```

So it looks like you want `InternetAddress.anyIPv4` for your value.